# Running Analytics on DataStax DSE graph

Tags: datastax, datastax-enterprise, datastax-startup, datastax-enterprise-graph

I have a large graph on DataStax DSE.

I'm trying to run some analytics queries. 
I've started with simple ones and I've noticed something

**Running without Analytics**

```
gremlin> :remote config alias g test.g
==>g=test.g
gremlin> g.V().hasLabel("person").has("id",5903806).count()
==>1
gremlin>
```

**Running with Analytics**

```
gremlin> :remote config alias g test.a
==>g=test.a
gremlin> g.V().hasLabel("person").has("id",5903806).count()
==>0
gremlin>
```

This can be some configuration issue ?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was in regards to specifying a float when the "id" property was a Text type. Wrapping the id in quotes solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

CristiC, we have an open defect for counts and OLAP ComputeEngine right now that will be addressed very shortly.  I can't tell if what you're seeing is related to this, but it likely is.  What version of DSE Graph are you using?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I use DSE 5.0.4 and I have the same behaviour with valueMap(true) not with count. And the issue is from DataStax studio and gremlin console

Comment: If I downgrade to lower DSE version it will solve my issue ? Thanks